# AppCompatActivity design

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

Why doesn't `AppCompatActivity`'s `getFragmentManager()` return a support version of the fragment manager?  Instead you have to both make your Activity an `AppCompatActivity` AND specifically call `getSupportFragmentManager()`.  The same is true for a dozen other methods.  It bugs me that you have to magically know which methods you can call as themselves, and which you have to rebrand as the "support" version.  Is there even any use case for wanting to call the "normal" version instead of the "support" version, when you're still supporting lower versions of Android?  It'd make a lot more sense to me if `AppCompatActivity` functioned indistinguishably from the later API versions of `Activity` - after all, that's what it's SUPPOSED to do, isn't it?  Provide the same functionality as the later API versions of `Activity`?

Is there some kind of design principle or hidden Java limitation that prevents them from doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn't AppCompatActivity's getFragmentManager() return a support version of the fragment manager?

Because it can't.

`Activity`, on API Level 11+, defines `getFragmentManager()` as returning an `android.app.FragmentManager`. The only way that `AppCompatActivity` could override it is if the overridden method *also* returns an `android.app.FragmentManager`. That's not possible. `AppCompatActivity` is designed to work back to API Level 7, where there is no `android.app.FragmentManager` to return. Hence, we have `getSupportFragmentManager()`, returning an `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`.

Note that `AppCompactActivity` really gets its fragments from `FragmentActivity`, which is designed to work back to API Level 4, two years before API Level 11 and native fragments were implemented.

Comment: Why not, for instance, have the support library define their own version of `android.app.FragmentManager`?  (I predict reasons of either "then the support version would conflict with the native version in later APIs" or "security reasons".  But I'm not sure.)

Comment: @Erhannis: "Why not, for instance, have the support library define their own version of android.app.FragmentManager?" -- because then the app using the library crashes on API Level 11+, with conflicting implementations of `android.app.FragmentManager`.

Comment: Hmm.  I'd be surprised if there weren't some tricky way around it with ClassLoaders and reflection, but I'll leave that be.  The other solution occurring to me would be for them to have subclassed Activity rather than adding methods to it, so AppCompatActivity and Activity11 or whatever both implement a getFragmentManager() with their own version of FragmentManager.  I can't say I like that approach, though; annoyingly untidy.  Fine, I yield; thanks.  I still don't really like all the "support" methods, though; it, too, is untidy.